Message Delete Logging to channel (javascript)
Im trying to make my discord bot log deleted messages like dyno im using discord.js v14 and for some reason the code below is not logging at all but im not receiving any errors and im very confused. To why there is no errors but it is not logging.
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const { getSettings } = require("@schemas/Guild");

module.exports = async (client, message) => {
  if (message.partial) return;
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

  const settings = await getSettings(message.guild);
  if (!settings.modlog_channel) return;

  const logChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(settings.modlog_channel);
  if (!logChannel) return;

  if (message.content) {
    // Log deleted message
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#FF5733")
      .setTitle("Message Deleted")
      .addFields(
        { name: "Content", value: message.content },
        { name: "Author", value: `${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id})`, inline: true },
        { name: "Channel", value: message.channel.toString(), inline: true }
      )
      .setFooter({ text: `Deleted at: ${new Date().toLocaleString()}` });

    logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
  }
};

im expecting it to send a embed to the logs channel as shows in code above with who deleted it what they deleted and so on.

Could you show how your client is defined? Specifically, what intents are you using? Also, it's possible that the message isn't cached or is partial, as you've told it to return in that case
